# Wifi HotSpot in Lumia 800

Tags: wifi, 7.5, nokia-lumia-800

I am using a `nokia lumia 800` windows phone having `OS windwos phone 7.5 mango`. Is there any way to use my phone as `wifi hotspot`? if anybody know please share..

Comment: Yes, I can, after an OS update two or three months ago.  However, it may depend on whether your phone carrier service has enabled it.  Look in Settings.

Comment: @paradroid I didn't find out a settings named carrier service . Is it directly under settings menu?

Comment: What I mean by carrier is your phone company.  In Settings, I have Internet Sharing, between Bluetooth and email+accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option was originally disabled by Nokia, although they did recently enable it -- if you haven't done so recently, connect via Zune and install any updates if you have any.

Wi-Fi sharing is in the settings menu, under "Internet Sharing".

For best results, only use with the phone on external power - even if that is the laptop you're providing power from is running on battery.